# AWS:Determining aws volume parameters from the linux system mountpoint

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, volume, devops

Need to get the AWS device mapping or other AWS EC2 volume parameters from the existing linux mount point [linux mapping is like `/dev/xvdf` for AWS mapping `/dev/sdf`], the EC2 CLI doesn't provide the solution for the same, please let me know of a solution.

Comment: Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

Try and do: `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/` **from within** the instance.

AWS has a [metadata/user-data API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval) that that you can query for this type of information.